# CentOS-7 Kernel Image has a "debug" suffix after a Kickstart installation

Tags: centos, grub2, kickstart

After finishing a customized CentOS-7 kickstart installation from a CDROM, the system has booted as expected and according to the ks.cfg file. 
At the grub menu the options I have are:

CentOS Linux, with Linux 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64.**debug**
in addition to the "rescue" option.

since I have another system (regular graphic installation) without the "debug" suffix in the menu entry, I was wondering if that suffix indicates any failures/problems/issues in the installed system, and if not - how I can customize this name.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `kernel-debug` package installed:

```
Description : The kernel package contains the Linux kernel (vmlinuz), the core of any
            : Linux operating system.  The kernel handles the basic functions
            : of the operating system:  memory allocation, process allocation, device
            : input and output, etc.
            :
            : This variant of the kernel has numerous debugging options enabled.
            : It should only be installed when trying to gather additional information 
            : on kernel bugs, as some of these options impact performance noticably.
```

Check your Kickstart script or remove the package with `yum`.

Comment: Indeed, I had to replace **kernel-debug**-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64.rpm with **kernel**-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64.rpm inside the generated KS ISO Image. It worked like a charm. thanks @garethTheRed